# CMFCToolBar dragging

Tags: mfc, toolbar

I have two [toolbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Mss.jpg),which I want to drag, but I have some conditions:

1. I don't need [close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x19Ug.jpg)
2. If it's real to do, I need to drag my toolbars only inside bars. I mean that I don't want to be floating in the client area, like in the previous picture. It was such in rebar before mfc pack!

Comment: I don't know about `1`, but `2` is fairly straight forward: Just calculate the effective rectangle the mouse is allowed to move to implement your restrictions, and apply it by calling [ClipCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. But I have another question - how can I find position (rect) of toolbars?

Comment: If the point 2. is true then 1. never happens. For 2. try https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20537570/How-can-I-lock-a-control-bar-so-it-won't-float.html#answer8066145